# SCSS import all file content as rules inside a selector

Tags: css, sass

I would like to import the content of a scss file, as css rules, inside a selector like this

```
html.dark {
    @import "_concatbootstrap-dark";
}
```

My problem is, at compilation time, the imported file is not compiled yet, and during compilation, selectors like

```
.btn-check + &
```

become

```
.btn-check + html.dark ...
```

instead of

```
html.dark .btn-check + ...
```

I know I could precompile the imported file, and then compile my html.dark, but I would like to know if there's a better way to achieve my compilation, in only one time, without precompiling, by using scss tricks.

Thanks in advance for your help